# Is there a way to tell Autofixture to only set properties with a specific attribute?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, dependency-injection, mocking, autofixture

I use Unity for dependency injection, and in a few places I use property injection (with the `[Dependency]` attribute) rather than constructor injection.

I'd like to use AutoFixture as a mocking container for my unit tests, but by default it sets all public properties on the system under test. I know I can explicitly exclude specific properties, but is there a way to include only properties that have the `[Dependency]` attribute?

Comment: Why are you using Property Injection?

Comment: @MarkSeemann, because in some situations it's more convenient. The typical use case is when I have an inheritance hierarchy; passing the dependencies to the base class constructor is hard to maintain, because if I had a dependency to the base class, I have to change all the derived class constructors.

Comment: That's not a good reason to use Property Injection. It's an attempt to [relieve the symptom instead of treating the disease](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6139076/126014) (be sure to read the comments as well). [Property Injection is only appropriate when the dependency is optional and you have an appropriate Local Default.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1985814/126014)

Comment: @MarkSeemann, thanks, but that's not the point. Property injection vs. constructor injection is an endless debate in which I don't want to participate. You only point me to your own answers, which of course support your point of view, but there are many people who disagree.

Comment: It's not an endless debate. AFAICT, it's mostly over by now, and Constructor Injection won. In chapter 4 of [my book on the subject](http://amzn.to/12p90MG), I have described in painstaking details all the problems with *implementing* Property Injection. There are clear, easy-to-explain reasons that Property Injection is a poor choice in most cases. From those who think differently, I've never heard any other argument that they 'prefer Property Injection', which is hardly an argument.

Comment: @MarkSeemann is right; it's not an endless debate. Don't use property injection!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This works:

```
public class PropertyBuilder : ISpecimenBuilder
{
    public object Create(object request, ISpecimenContext context)
    {
        var pi = request as PropertyInfo;
        if (pi != null)
        {
            if (pi.IsDefined(typeof (DependencyAttribute)))
                return context.Resolve(pi.PropertyType);

            //"hey, don't set this property"
            return new OmitSpecimen();
        }

        //"i don't know how to handle this request - go ask some other ISpecimenBuilder"
        return new NoSpecimen(request);
    }
}

fixture.Customizations.Add(new PropertyBuilder());
```

Test case:

```
public class DependencyAttribute : Attribute
{
}

public class TestClass
{
    [Dependency]
    public string With { get; set; }

    public string Without { get; set; }
}

[Fact]
public void OnlyPropertiesWithDependencyAttributeAreResolved()
{
    // Fixture setup
    var fixture = new Fixture
    {
        Customizations = {new PropertyBuilder()}
    };
    // Exercise system
    var sut = fixture.Create<TestClass>();
    // Verify outcome
    Assert.NotNull(sut.With);
    Assert.Null(sut.Without);
}
```

Comment: This works great, I just wrapped it in a ICustomization for a more fluent usage. Thanks!